# Debug in Facebook In-App Browser like Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, react-hooks, facebook-browser

I'm currently wanting to detect if I'm browsing through facebook in app browser or other web Browser. but how can I know if I'm in Facebook in-app browser. I want to see the console log. I would also like to know if I'm viewing it in the browser or webview browser.

I have a code like this

```
function isFacebookApp() {
var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera
  return ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1 || ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1
}

{isFacebookApp == true ? (
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>
            This is from Facebook Browser
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>
            {result.browser.name}
          </div>
        )}
```

But when I'm opening my app in Facebook in-app browser. it Still show me that I'm using Chrome v96. What seems to be the problem?